# I would like to have a text box alert a user when they input an incorrect character

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-core

Here is what I currently have, I have tried expanding the if statement to have a MessageBox appear and alear the user on keypress but I haven't had any luck. Here is what I have that works and limits user input. In Windows Forms.

```
private void PhoneText_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar) && !char.IsControl(e.KeyChar))
        {
            e.Handled = true;

        }            
    }
```

Comment: Apparently no messages will be displayed, because code does not have any. Did you tried to show MessageBox, if so can you show a code with such call?

Answer (score 0):

in the else condition for example, change the back color:

```
if (!char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar) && !char.IsControl(e.KeyChar))
{
    e.Handled = true;
    PhoneText.BackColor = Color.White;
} 
else
{
    PhoneText.BackColor = Color.IndianRed;
}
```

Comment: This is not a solution for an issue.

Comment: Ok, so with that code, it is turning red when I type in numbers but nothing is happening when I press letter keys. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Modify your code to:

```
    if (!char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar) && !char.IsControl(e.KeyChar))
    {
        e.Handled = true;
        MessageBox.Show("Incorrect Character!");
    }
```

I usually use this piece to allow only numerics and decimals:

```
        Char chr = e.KeyChar;
        if (!char.IsDigit(chr) && e.KeyChar!='.')
        {
            e.Handled = true;
            MessageBox.Show("Please enter only numeric values.");
        }
```

Comment: @sswifty6:     If the answer helps you, you should mark it as the answer. If not, you can comment and inform the person about the errors so that he is able to help you.